# NSD_CreateText not populating stack

Tags: stack, installation, nsis

For my NSIS script I need some user info, so I have the following code:

```
Function tomcatConfig
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "$(TEXT_CONF_TITLE)" "$(TEXT_CONF_SUBTITLE)"

nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 2u 100u 14u "Tomcat shutdown port"
Pop $R0
${NSD_CreateText} 150u 0 50u 12u "8005"
Pop $CtlTomcatPortShutdown
${NSD_SetTextLimit} $CtlTomcatPortShutdown 5

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 19u 100u 14u "Tomcat default http port"
Pop $R0
${NSD_CreateText} 150u 17u 50u 12u "80"
Pop $CtlTomcatPortHttp
${NSD_SetTextLimit} $CtlTomcatPortHttp 5

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 36u 100u 14u "Tomcat default https port"
Pop $R0
${NSD_CreateText} 150u 34u 50u 12u "443"
Pop $CtlTomcatPortSSL
${NSD_SetTextLimit} $CtlTomcatPortSSL 5

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 57u 140u 14u "Tomcat service name"
Pop $R0
${NSD_CreateText} 150u 55u 140u 12u "Servicename"
Pop $CtlTomcatServiceName

${NSD_SetFocus} $CtlTomcatPortShutdown

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```

When I am using `$CtlTomcatPortShutdown`, `$CtlTomcatPortHttp`, `$CtlTomcatPortHttp`, `$CtlTomcatServiceName` in my script, I get returned some random number, instead of the input I expect (service name, port numbers etc.).

This sample from NSIS NsDialog page also looks invalid on Windows 10, when I use `$Text` I am returned a random number as well.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Name nsDialogs
OutFile nsDialogs.exe

XPStyle on

Var Dialog
Var Label
Var Text

Page custom nsDialogsPage
Page instfiles

Function nsDialogsPage

nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $Dialog

${If} $Dialog == error
Abort
${EndIf}

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
Pop $Label

${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% -13u "Type something here..."
Pop $Text

nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Section
DetailPrint "hello $Text"

SectionEnd
```

Comment: I recommend you use [NSIS Dialog Designer](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/nsisdialogdesigner). A great tool for designing installer custom pages.

Comment: The basic example on NSIS also returns a random number, maybe it is something with NSIS and Windows 10..

Answer (score 1):

The ${NSD_CreateXYZ} macros return the [handle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing)) (HWND) to the control on the stack, not a random number. This handle can be used in calls to `${NSD_GetText}` and `${NSD_SetText}` etc.